# How to change the locale in Flowbite datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, tailwind-css, flowbite

Unfortunately the [Flowbite Datepicker](https://flowbite.com/docs/plugins/datepicker/) Documentation has no instruction on how to use another locale, but the [support is there](https://github.com/themesberg/tailwind-datepicker/tree/master/js/i18n/locales).

This is how I implemented the datepicker (working):

```js
import Datepicker from "flowbite-datepicker/Datepicker";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.querySelectorAll("[datepicker]").forEach(function (datepickerEl) {
    new Datepicker(datepickerEl);
  });
});
```

and this is how I try to get the locale to work:

```js
import Datepicker from "flowbite-datepicker/Datepicker";
import { locales } from "../../node_modules/flowbite-datepicker/js/i18n/base-locales.js";
import de from "../../node_modules/flowbite-datepicker/js/i18n/locales/de.js";

locales.de = de;

const datepickerOptions = {
  language: "de",
  weekStart: 1,
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.querySelectorAll("[datepicker]").forEach(function (datepickerEl) {
    const d = new Datepicker(datepickerEl);
    d.setOptions(datepickerOptions);
  });
});
```

But my modular Javascript understanding is too poor to get this right. [This](https://github.com/themesberg/tailwind-datepicker/blob/master/js/Datepicker.js) is the file to reference the original code. Should be straight forward for someone with more experience.

Comment: Have you tried passing in `locale` in `datepickerOptions`?
const datepickerOptions = {
  language: "de",
  weekStart: 1,
locale:de
};

You can do something like new Datepicker(datepickerEl, datepickerOptions)

Comment: Can you also provide the code of the HTML parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `locales.de = de`, try `Datepicker.locales.de = de`.

Check out this [reference](https://github.com/themesberg/tailwind-datepicker/blob/master/dist/js/locales/de.js#L6) from the source repository.

Comment: It's working with `Datepicker.locales.de = de.de`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that flowbite-datepicker is forked from vanillajs-datepicker, and after checking their [docs](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/i18n) I got the following code to work:

```
import Datepicker from "flowbite-datepicker/Datepicker";
import ja from "flowbite-datepicker/locales/ja";

const datepickerEl = document.getElementById("datepickerId");
Object.assign(Datepicker.locales, ja);
const datePicker = new Datepicker(datepickerEl, {
  language: 'ja',
});
```